# NFS won't unmount "/mnt/nfs: not mounted"

Tags: mount, nfs, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I mounted the NFS share using:

```
$ sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.1.1:/foo /mnt/nfs
```

For some reason it failed (ls doesn't show any content from the nfs server)

It then shows like:

```
$ sudo mount 
192.168.1.1:/foo on /mnt/nfs type nfs (rw,vers=4,addr=192.168.1.1,clientaddr=192.168.1.2)
```

However when I try to umount, it fails:

```
$ sudo umount /mnt/nfs 
umount.nfs: /mnt/nfs: not mounted
```

Rebooting didn't kill the entry, nor did removing the nfs directory from /mnt/nfs Same with `umount -f`

Trying to mount again with different options gives me duplicate entries, and trying to umount gives me a corresponding "not mounted" message for each duplicate.

Any suggestions on how to clear out these failed mounts?

Environment:

- Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS  on Linux Subsystem for Windows 10
- nfs-common version is 1.2.8-6ubuntu1.2

Comment: 'df -h' shows you what filesystems that are mounted.

Comment: You don't need super-user privileges to run `mount` without arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: mounting network drives is not supported in Bash/WSL at present. If you would like to see this feature in future releases, please [upvote here](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/13600230-mount-nfs-sshfs-samba-smb-network-drives).